# DecimalFormats and Return statements

Tags: java

For my college class, I have to create a program that calculates the midpoint on a line. I have most of the core program worked out, but I need some help.

```
public double calculateMidpointX() { // acessor
    xmid = (calcX1 + calcX2) / 2.0;
    return (xmid);
}
```

...

```
DecimalFormat num = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
```

How do I return `xmid` with the `DecimalFormat("###.##");` 
Is there a specific syntax I need to be looking at? What if I used System.out.println?

Comment: You don't and nor should you really want to.  Return the raw result and, when you need to, use a `DecimalFormat` to simply format the output

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Not sure what the question is?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will this work? `System.out.print (num.format(lineOne.calculateMidpointx()));`

Comment: @m4gnet Should do, try it.  Formatting really is just a way of making a value "look" the way you want it, what the value actually is (or how it's stored) should be irrelevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   System.out.println(calculateMidpointX(1.373,3)); // Print 2.19
  }


  public static double calculateMidpointX(double x, double y) { 

    DecimalFormat num = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    Double xmid = (x + y) / 2.0;
    return (Double.parseDouble(num.format(xmid))); // This return 2.19
  }
```

If i only use `return xmid;` without format it, it will return `2.1865`.